# Finding the likelihood ratio to test which distribution has the largest mean

Tags: hypothesis-testing, maximum-likelihood, optimization, likelihood-ratio, neyman-pearson-lemma

**The problem:** Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ and $Y_1, \ldots, Y_m$ be two i.i.d. samples drawn from $\mathcal{N}(\mu_x, \sigma^2)$ and $\mathcal{N}(\mu_y, \sigma^2)$, respectively. I wanna test $H_0: \mu_x \leq \mu_y$ against $H_1:\mu_x > \mu_y$ using the likelihood ratio test.

The joint distribution of these samples is:

$$f_\theta(\textbf{x}, \textbf{y}) = (2\pi \sigma^2)^{-(n + m)/2} \exp\left [ -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} \left( \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \mu_x)^2 + \sum_{j=1}^m (y_j - \mu_y)^2 \right )\right]$$

The likelihood ratio statistic is:

$$\lambda = \frac{\sup_{\theta \in \Theta_0} f_\theta(\bf{x}, \bf{y})}{\sup_{\theta \in \Theta} f_\theta (\bf{x}, \bf{y})}$$

I was able to find the denominator, the unconstrained $\sup$, which occurs at the maximum likelihood point $\theta = \left (\bar{x}, \bar{y}, \hat{\sigma}^2\right )$, however I'm unable to find $\sup_{\theta \in \Theta_0} f_\theta(\bf{x}, \bf{y})$ because of the constraint $\mu_x \leq \mu_y$. How do I deal with this?

Notation:

$\Theta = \{(\mu_x, \mu_y, \sigma^2): -\infty < \mu_x, \mu_y < \infty, \sigma^2 > 0 \}$

$\Theta_0 = \{(\mu_x, \mu_y, \sigma^2): -\infty < \mu_x \leq \mu_y < \infty, \sigma^2 > 0 \}$

$\textbf{x} = (x_1, \ldots, x_n), \;\; \textbf{y} = (y_1, \ldots, y_m)$

$\hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{(n - 1)s_x^2 + (m - 1)s_y^2}{n + m}$

$s_x^2 = \frac{1}{n - 1} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2,\;\; s_y^2 = \frac{1}{m - 1} \sum_{j=1}^m (y_j - \bar{y})^2$

Comment: You cannot use a likelihood ratio test for non-nested models.

Comment: @Xi'an why is this model non-nested?

Comment: $H_0:\mu_x<\mu_y$ vs $H_a:\mu_x>\mu_y$ do not intersect.

Comment: @Xi'an $H_0$ is $\mu_x \leq \mu_y$